# How to add JAR files to a Liberty java web application in Bluemix with WEB-INF missing?

Tags: jar, ibm-cloud, web-inf

i need to add a jar file to a Liberty application in Bluemix. The WEB-INF folder is missing. How can i do that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The WEB-INF folder shouldn't be missing, it should include at least your web.xml configuration file and your lib directory, where the liberty runtime is expecting to find the libraries you want to upload along with your application

Comment: With bluemix, when i create a simple java web app. The project folder doesn't include WEB-INF. Do i need to create it manually ?

Comment: the easiest way is to add a GIT repository to your liberty profile and download the code from there, the directory structure for your project will be created already and available from there

Comment: Ok i find it, thanks. And for the custom jar file. I add have just to add it manually ?

Comment: @AbderrazakL yes.
Anyway which is the application runtime you choose that creates a starter code without the WEB-INF directory?

Comment: liberty for java runtime

Answer (score 0):

Your java web application must have a WEB-INF directory.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html

If you can't find it in your project, you can double click in your liberty in the bluemix console and inspect the liberty instance files, like this

[image]

WEB-INF should be at

app->wlp->usr->servers->defaultServer->apps->myapp.war->WEB-INF->libs